# Print the edition as an apex/superscript after the year in

Tags: biblatex

The requirements of my institution impose in bibliography to specify the edition as an apex to the year of publication.

I'm using verbose-trad2 style and Italian babel specifications, so this entry:

```
@book{fittizio,
author       = {Paolo Polesana},
title        = {De Polesanis},
year         = {1980},
edition = {2},
publisher    = {s.n.},
location     = {Bresso},
}
```

gives this result

[image]

I have to obtain this instead:

[image]

Comment: Use moewe's [biblatex-ext](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext), your case is already covered in the manual on page 34 → http://mirror.physik-pool.tu-berlin.de/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf

Comment: Thank you DG'. It worked properly

Comment: @DG' Do you want to type up a quick answer here (with the necessary changes for this use case) or do you want Paolo to self-answer. In any case it would be nice if this question got an answer in the end, either by DG' or by PaoloPolesana.

Comment: In any case, I wrote an answer

Comment: Thanks, that's great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in [biblatex-ext](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) manual at page 34, define the macro `superedition` to be used after `\usebibmacro{date}`:

```
\documentclass[italian]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-verbose-trad2, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{edition}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}} 

\newbibmacro*{superedition}{%
  \iffieldnums{edition} 
    {\printfield[superedition]{edition}} 
    {\printfield{edition}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}}

\renewcommand*{\pubdatedelim}{\addspace} 
\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\pubdatedelim} 

\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}% 
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}% 
  \printlist{#1}% 
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}% 
  \usebibmacro{date}% 
  \usebibmacro{superedition}% 
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{fittizio,
  author     = {Paolo Polesana},
  title      = {De Polesanis},
  year       = {1980},
  edition    = {2},
  publisher  = {s.n.},
  location   = {Bresso},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{fittizio}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Polesana, Paolo. De Polesanis. Bresso: s.n. 19802.]

Comment: Please consider posting fully compilable example documents instead of code snippets in the future. That makes questions easier to answer (it ensures we are all talking about the same thing) and answers easier to apply. I turned the code into a compilable example document. Hope you don't mind.