# How to remove space between Edition and Year

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'd like to remove the space between the edition and the year but I don't know how.

To explain: I put the edition before the year by changing the bibmacro `publisher+location+date` and removing `\printfield{edition}` from the bibliography driver. I did the same for in collection but I didn't put it up here. I don't know if that's the best solution but it works

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle-ibid, pagetracker=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}

\DeclareFieldFormat{edition}{\textsuperscript{#1}} %Auflage hochgestellt

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%kein Komma nach Verlag und Auflage vor Datum
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
 \printfield{edition}
  \usebibmacro{date}%
\newunit}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  %\printfield{edition}%Edition ausblenden
  %\newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{filecontents}{literatur.bib}
@book{ZimmerlingCharismatisch,
author = {Zimmerling, Peter},
title = {Charismatische Bewegungen},
publisher = {Vandenhoeck \& Ruprecht},
location = {Göttingen},
year = {2018},
Edition = {2}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}

\begin{document}
Text \footcite{ZimmerlingCharismatisch}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code almost does what you want. You just need a `%` after `\printfield{edition}`. In LaTeX the end of a line behaves like a space and may therefore cause a space to appear in the output unless it is commented out with `%`. See [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) for a more thorough discussion.

So

```
\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
```

will work as intended.

---

In the [`biblatex-ext` documentation (§5.4 *Selected bibliography macros*, p. 33 in v0.14)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf) I suggest the following shorter solution.

It only requires a switch from `style=authortitle-ibid,` to `style=ext-authortitle-ibid,`. (This change will otherwise have no effect on the output. `ext-authortitle-ibid` is a drop-in replacement for `authortitle-ibid`.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=guillemets]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=ext-authortitle-ibid, pagetracker=false]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibcompletename}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}

\renewbibmacro*{edition}{}

\DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
\newbibmacro*{superedition}{%
  \iffieldnums{edition}
    {\printfield[superedition]{edition}}
    {\printfield{edition}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}}

\renewcommand*{\pubdatedelim}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\locdatedelim}{\pubdatedelim}
\renewbibmacro*{pubinstorg+location+date}[1]{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{#1}
    {\setunit*{\locdatedelim}}
    {\setunit*{\locpubdelim}}%
  \printlist{#1}%
  \setunit*{\pubdatedelim}%
  \usebibmacro{superedition}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ZimmerlingCharismatisch,
  author    = {Zimmerling, Peter},
  title     = {Charismatische Bewegungen},
  publisher = {Vandenhoeck \& Ruprecht},
  location  = {Göttingen},
  year      = {2018},
  Edition   = {2},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Text\autocite{ZimmerlingCharismatisch}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Zimmerling, Peter: Charismatische Bewegungen. Göttingen: Vandenhoeck & Ruprecht 22018.]

The idea here is to avoid having to modify the bibliography driver, which would need lots of code, by using the new `edition` bibmacro from `biblatex-ext` to disable the "usual" edition printing.

Then we just need to add the edition to the date. This is done in the meta macro `pubinstorg+location+date`, which ultimately ends up defining `publisher+location+date` as in your example.

See also [Print the edition as an apex/superscript after the year in](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560267/35864) (or https://golatex.de/viewtopic.php?p=107206#p107206 in the German goLaTeX forum).