# Biblatex edition as superscript behind year

Tags: biblatex

My bibliography needs to show the edition behind the year for `@collection` and `@incollection` like this:

> Kuckartz, U. (2018⁴): Qualitative Inhaltsanalyse: Methoden, Praxis, Computerunterstützung. Weinheim: Beltz
>
> Ryen, A. (2016⁴): Research ethics and qualitative research. In: Silverman, D. (ed.): Qualitative research. Los Angeles: Sage, 31-46.

I already found several posts that deal with similar issues which I tried to adapt, e.g.:

1. [Print the edition as an apex/superscript after the year in](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/560267/print-the-edition-as-an-apex-superscript-after-the-year-in)
2. [BibLaTeX: Edition as superscript in front of year, but year after author(s)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319683/biblatex-edition-as-superscript-in-front-of-year-but-year-after-authors?rq=1)

I managed to get the edition as a superscript behind the year and inside parentheses. However, there is a space before and after the year.

[image]

MWE with the adapted code from the two linked posts:

```
  \documentclass[]{scrartcl}
            \usepackage{filecontents}
            \usepackage[
                        backend=biber,
                        style=ext-authoryear,
                        innamebeforetitle=true,
                        sorting=nyt,
                        giveninits=true,
                        citestyle= authoryear-icomp,
                        ibidpage=true,
                        maxbibnames=99,
                        maxcitenames=2,
                        uniquelist=false,
                        isbn=false,
                        doi=true,
                        dashed=false
                                     ]{biblatex}
    
   %Edition as superscript
    \renewbibmacro*{edition}{}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
    \newbibmacro*{superedition}{%
        \iffieldnums{edition}
        {\printfield[superedition]{edition}}
        {\printfield{edition}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}}
    
    %Year^Edition within parentheses
    \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{
      \iffieldundef{labelyear}
        {}
        {\printtext[parens]{
        \iflabeldateisdate
             {\printdateextra}
             {\printlabeldateextra}
        \iffieldnum{edition}
             {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
              \global\clearfield{edition}}
             {}}}}
    
    
     \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}         
                                             
                @book{kuckartz_qualitative_2018,
                    location = {Weinheim},
                    edition = {4},
                    title = {Qualitative Inhaltsanalyse: Methoden, Praxis, Computerunterstützung},
                    publisher = {Beltz},
                    author = {Kuckartz, Udo},
                    date = {2018},}
    
                @incollection{ryen_research_2016,
                    location = {Los Angeles},
                    edition = {4},
                    title = {Research ethics and qualitative research},
                    pages = {31--46},
                    booktitle = {Qualitative research},
                    publisher = {Sage},
                    author = {Ryen, Anne},
                    editor = {Silverman, David},
                    date = {2016},}
                
             \end{filecontents}
             
             \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    
             \begin{document}
                 \nocite{*}
                 \printbibliography
             \end{document}
```

I already removed all other modifications to see, if one of them is the reason for the additional spaces, but I sill got the spaces before and after YEAR. I have the feeling that I should modify something about `\pubdatedelim` but I could be mistaken because nothing I tried worked.

In case it is helpful for the answer, below is also the full code, including the other modifications of the bibliography:

```
     \documentclass[]{scrartcl}
        \usepackage{filecontents}
        \usepackage[
                    backend=biber,
                    style=ext-authoryear,
                    innamebeforetitle=true,
                    sorting=nyt,
                    giveninits=true,
                    citestyle= authoryear-icomp,
                    ibidpage=true,
                    maxbibnames=99,
                    maxcitenames=2,
                    uniquelist=false,
                    isbn=false,
                    doi=true,
                    dashed=false
                                 ]{biblatex}
        
         %%% Modifications that work as intended %%%%

         \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}} %Small caps for author/editor last name
            
         \DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}                  %Title without emphasis
         \DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}              %Booktitle without emphasis
         \DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}           %Journaltitle without emphasis
            
            
            
         \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist,parencite]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space} % use   semicolon to seperate authors in bibliography and citation in text
            
          \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist,parencite]{finalnamedelim}{\space\&\space} % use & to seperate last author/editor in bibliography
            
          \DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} % use colon to seperate (Year) and Title
            
          \DeclareDelimFormat[textcite, parencite]{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space} % use colon to seperate Year and page in citation

%%% Authors and Editors as Family-Given, except last author/editor:

         \DeclareNameFormat{family-given/given-family/last}{%
               \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{listtotal}}} or test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}}} 
                {\ifgiveninits
                   {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
                     {\namepartfamily}
                     {\namepartgiveni}
                     {\namepartprefix}
                     {\namepartsuffix}}
                   {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
                     {\namepartfamily}
                     {\namepartgiven}
                     {\namepartprefix}
                     {\namepartsuffix}}%
                 \ifboolexpe{%
                   test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
                   and
                   test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
                   {}
                   {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
                 {\ifgiveninits
                 {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
                   {\namepartfamily}
                   {\namepartgiveni}
                   {\namepartprefix}
                   {\namepartsuffix}}
                {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
                   {\namepartfamily}
                   {\namepartgiven}
                   {\namepartprefix}
                   {\namepartsuffix}}}%
                \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
  
          \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family/last}
          \DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{sortname}



            %%%% Volume (Issue) for @article
          \renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\space} %Removes dot between volume and issue
          \DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{(#1)} %Parentheses around Issue

            %%% Remove p. and pp.
          \DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
          \DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
          \DeclareFieldFormat{volcitepages}{\mknormrange{#1}}
          \DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

          %Substitute Ed by with (ed.)
         \DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}
         \DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}

         \DeclareFieldAlias{translatortype}{editortype}
         \DeclareDelimAlias{translatortypedelim}{editortypedelim}

%%% Edition as superscript --  space before and after YEAR is yet to be removed %%%

      %Edition as superscript
        \renewbibmacro*{edition}{}
        \DeclareFieldFormat{superedition}{\textsuperscript{#1}}
        \newbibmacro*{superedition}{%
            \iffieldnums{edition}
            {\printfield[superedition]{edition}}
            {\printfield{edition}%
            \setunit{\addspace}}}
        
        %Year^Edition within parentheses
        \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}{
          \iffieldundef{labelyear}
            {}
            {\printtext[parens]{
            \iflabeldateisdate
                 {\printdateextra}
                 {\printlabeldateextra}
            \iffieldnum{edition}
                 {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
                  \global\clearfield{edition}}
                 {}}}}





        \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}         
                                         
            @book{kuckartz_qualitative_2018,
                location = {Weinheim},
                edition = {4},
                title = {Qualitative Inhaltsanalyse: Methoden, Praxis, Computerunterstützung},
                publisher = {Beltz},
                author = {Kuckartz, Udo},
                date = {2018},}

            @incollection{ryen_research_2016,
                location = {Los Angeles},
                edition = {4},
                title = {Research ethics and qualitative research},
                pages = {31--46},
                booktitle = {Qualitative research},
                publisher = {Sage},
                author = {Ryen, Anne},
                editor = {Silverman, David},
                date = {2016},}
            
         \end{filecontents}
         
         \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

         \begin{document}
             \nocite{*}
             \printbibliography
         \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are introducing the white space yourself into your code.

Try this:

```
        %Year^Edition within parentheses
        \renewbibmacro*{date+extradate}
            {\iffieldundef{labelyear}{}%
                {\printtext[parens]%
                    {\iflabeldateisdate{\printdateextra}%
                        {\printlabeldateextra}\iffieldnum{edition}%
                            {\printfield[superedition]{edition}%
                            \global\clearfield{edition}}{}%
                    }
                }
            }
```

Note the comment signs at the end of each line.

PS: It should be `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solved the problem and works as it should.